Pytorch resnet wrong predictions
I am using the pytorch resnet for the first time (model = models.segmentation.fcn_resnet50(pretrained=True)) to classify satellite images of land. My goal is to get the percentage of the land covered by forests. For input, I have satellite images, and there is a mask associated with them that is color-coded (forests, farmland, urban area, water, etc.).
I made my own Data Structure in pytorch and then called the model, but somewhere, it's going wrong. I think it's because I'm not inputing the color coding but I'm not sure.
Here is what it should look like:

And here is what happens:

Here is the code for the data:
label_colors = {
    'urban_land': (0, 255, 255),
    'agriculture_land': (255, 255, 0),
    'rangeland': (255, 0, 255),
    'forest_land': (0, 255, 0),
    'water': (0, 0, 255),
    'barren_land': (255, 255, 255),
    'unknown': (0, 0, 0)
}

class ImageMaskDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, image_dir, mask_dir, transform=None, mask_transform=None):
        self.image_dir = image_dir
        self.mask_dir = mask_dir
        self.transform = transform
        self.mask_transform = mask_transform
        self.images = [img for img in os.listdir(image_dir) if img.endswith('_sat.jpg')]
        self.masks = [self._find_mask(img) for img in self.images]

    def _find_mask(self, image_filename):
        base = image_filename.split('_sat')[0]
        mask_filename = f"{base}_mask.png"
        return mask_filename

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.images)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        img_name = self.images[idx]
        mask_name = self.masks[idx]
        img_path = os.path.join(self.image_dir, img_name)
        mask_path = os.path.join(self.mask_dir, mask_name)

        image = io.imread(img_path)
        mask = io.imread(mask_path)

        if self.transform:
            image = self.transform(image)
        if self.mask_transform:
            mask = self.mask_transform(mask)

        return image, mask

And here is the code for running on the model:
def main():
    # Create a model
    model = models.segmentation.fcn_resnet50(pretrained=True)
    model.eval()  # Set the model to evaluation mode if not training

    # Dataset and DataLoader
    image_directory = '/Users/archive/train3/images'
    mask_directory = '/Users/archive/train3/masks'


    transform = Compose([
    ToTensor(),  # Converts numpy array to tensor
    Resize((256, 256))  # Resize the tensor
    ])

    # Assuming transform and dataset setup includes necessary transformations
    dataset = ImageMaskDataset(image_directory, mask_directory, transform= transform)
    dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=1, shuffle=True)

    device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
    model.to(device)

    with torch.no_grad():
        for images, _ in dataloader:
            images = images.to(device)
            output = model(images)['out']
            print(output)
            print(output.shape)
            probabilities = torch.nn.functional.softmax(output, dim=1)
            _, predicted_masks = torch.max(probabilities, dim=1)
            predicted_mask = predicted_masks.squeeze(0)

            color_mask = class_to_rgb(predicted_mask, label_colors)
            print(color_mask)
             # Get the most likely class for each pixel

            # Visualization
            plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
            plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
            plt.imshow(images[0].cpu().permute(1, 2, 0))  # Assuming the image is a torch.Tensor
            plt.title('Original Image')
            plt.axis('off')

            plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
            plt.imshow(predicted_mask)
            plt.title('Segmentation Output')
            plt.axis('off')

            plt.show()

            # Optionally, break after the first batch for demonstration
            break


def class_to_rgb(prediction, label_colors):
    """Convert class index predictions to RGB color image for visualization."""
    color_mask = torch.zeros(prediction.shape + (3,), dtype=torch.uint8)
    for class_idx, color in enumerate(label_colors.values()):
        color_mask[prediction == class_idx] = torch.tensor(color, dtype=torch.uint8)
    return color_mask


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Can someone tell me where I went wrong or if there is a crucial thing that I need to change?
I tried googling, asking ChatGPT, and asking peers, but none worked. I expected it to be a bug and to find it soon.
